# Jobs > Apply Now > Autofill data old

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

When I clicked "Apply Now" for SO jobs, the autofill content was populating the name, email, phone num, location, resume, and "introduce yourself" fields with data that has since been changed within the site's settings and profile.

Having applied to one company, the autofill now populates the data with the latest changes.

The bug is that autofill has old data cached, that may or may not be relevant to the user anymore, that should have been updated when that specific data was change within the settings/profile.

Comment: When you say settings/profile do you mean developer story or your SO user profile?

Comment: The tabs are as follows: Profile, Activity, Developer Story, Edit Profile & Settings
I mean SO user profile, because the developer story does not have email, however you may edit name within the DS profile. Location, phone num(My contact phone num was blank), resume, comes from Job Preferences, so the sources are varied. There is no field for "Introduce Yourself"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmmm, this is largely by design; we always use the data that you gave on your last application. The reason is that often people use different information on their profile than what they would provide to an employer.

That said, I can totally see why you'd expect the more recent information on your profile to be used *by default*. But at what threshold should we consider the data on the application out-of-date? If you updated your profile five minutes after sending an application should we use your profile for your next application? Or should we always take whatever data was most recently updated (e.g. if you subsequently fill out an application with data that is different to your profile should we use that instead)?

Drop your thoughts in the comments, I'll bring it up with the team.

Comment: When I provide details on my profile, then I want that data to be the default. It is the data I can see and modify, the most up to date. If the majority uses different data for the majority of the fields then I can understand the caches usefulness, but it is not "normal" autofill behaviour. Perhaps an autofill feature with different information profiles would be better suited at capturing the different information that one would want to send to each company.