# Email wrong when using Jobs Easy Apply

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I changed my Stack Overflow email a few months ago. I've been looking at the Easy Apply feature on SO Jobs recently, and I've noticed that even though my name appears correct in the application (I changed how my name was shown at the same time as the email address), it is showing my old email by default. I've checked the email preferences section of my preferences, and it is correct there.

Is this cached wrong somewhere, or am I missing a place I would also need to change my email? I don't see any email-related options in the Jobs section of the site preferences.

Update:

I see [a similar question from a while back here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370666/jobs-apply-now-autofill-data-old). I have used the Easy Apply function with corrected email and it is still showing the old email autofilled when I start a new Easy Apply application. If it is supposed to use your last used info from a previous application, it isn't doing so, but I still feel that not updating my contact email when I change my email address is extremely confusing UX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to your [email settings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current) you can change the email address used for jobs. If you change them to the same value then they'll remain in sync.

Comment: Glad to hear I was just missing something somewhat obvious! I somehow didn't see the second email box on that page. Thank you